# Limiting input to specified regexp with uppercase chars in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm trying to limit what our users will be able to type in inputs, using javascript/jquery.

Problem is, I have to limit this to Uppercase chars only, and numbers.

Here's what I coded previously :

```
$(input).keypress(function(e){
                    if ($(input).attr("class")=="populationReference"){
                        var ValidPattern = /^[A-Z_0-9]*$/;
                        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
                        if (!ValidPattern.test(char) && e.charCode!=0){
                            return false;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

If Firefox supports charCode, IE doesn't. How then, could I test if the user is typing uppercase or lowercase characters ?
Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jquery manual for [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> To determine which character was
>   entered, we can examine the event
>   object that is passed to the handler
>   function. While browsers use differing
>   attributes to store this information,
>   jQuery normalizes the .which attribute
>   so we can reliably use it to retrieve
>   the character code.

In other words, if you are using jquery, you are safe to use `e.which` to return the character code, so in your case:

```
var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
```

is the change to make.

But personally, I would avoid punishing users for lower-case input by converting it for them. Maybe add this modification:

```
$("input.populationReference").keypress(function(e){
                        var ValidPattern = /^[A-Z_a-z_0-9]*$/;
                        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
                        if (!ValidPattern.test(char) && e.charCode!=0){
                            return false;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                          var inputval = $(this).value(); 
                          $(this).value(inputval.toUpperCase());
                        }
                });
```

Comment: this made it. One more question : what about TAB and ARROW keys ? with the above code, none of them works. Is there a way to special treat them ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `keypress()` event instead.  In IE, all `keydown` and `keyup` specify which keyboard key code was pressed -- it doesn't take control keys into account and modify the keycode accordingly.  The `keypress` event specifies which character code was typed.  Be aware that it will not work for certain system keys:

> As of Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0, the onkeypress event fires and can be canceled for the following keys:
>
> - Letters: A - Z (uppercase and lowercase)
>
>   Numerals: 0 - 9
>
>   Symbols: ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = System: ESC, SPACEBAR, ENTER

Since your edit -- you need to use `e.which` instead of `e.charCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.which` instead of `e.charCode` as well.