# String.fromCharCode not working on keydown event

Tags: javascript, keydown

I am tyring to read the input characters on keydown event and try to process them. When I am triing to convert them into character using "String.fromCharCode(key);" Its always giving me the capital letters.

**Upadte:
Strangely the code works if I listen for "keypress" event. What is the reason for this. Could some one please explain this behavoir.**

The sample code is given below:

```
var inp = document.getElementById("ti");

inp.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(e) {
    if (window.event) {
        var key = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=  String.fromCharCode(key);
}
```

**What is the best practice to read the character on keydown event**

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZtW9/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zZtW9/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks, what is the reason for this. Could you please explain this behavoir. What is the best practice when handling keyboard events

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568494/keyup-event-always-return-uppercase-letter

Comment: `keypress` will give you correct char code, that's the main difference. Use `keydown` and `keyup` for special characters. But you could just assign the value of the input to the div http://jsfiddle.net/zZtW9/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try `keypress` instead of `keydown`

```
 inp.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyDown);
```

> In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zZtW9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Guess you only need to change the EventListener to keypress

```
var inp = document.getElementById("ti");

inp.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown(e) {
    if (window.event) {
        var key = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(key);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zZtW9/4/

Take a look here,you can note learn the differences from here :
http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/HTML-event-attributes-completed.php

EDIT: For your doubt,check this :
[keyup event always return uppercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568494/keyup-event-always-return-uppercase-letter?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module called [keysight](https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight) that translates `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events into characters and keys respectively.

Example:

```
 inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var character = keysight(event).char
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML +=  character
 })
```