# How to only get the key pressed inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I am trying to get the key pressed inside a div. But I am not sure how to just get the key pressed. Currently as I try to press the key nothing happens.

The way I am doing is.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="d"> </div>

<p id="log"></p>


const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("onkeyup", logKey)

function logKey(e) {
   log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
}
```

Here is also the jsfiddle corresponding to it: https://jsfiddle.net/hpeLqmyg/

How could I do this?

Comment: Change "onkeyup" to "keyup"

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722589/how-to-bind-keyboard-events-to-div-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind keyboard events to div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722589/how-to-bind-keyboard-events-to-div-elements)

Answer (score 2):

change `onkeyup` to `keyup`

`document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("keyup", logKey)`

https://jsfiddle.net/2x8pcu0m/

Comment: How to get the key pressed? `e.code` gives the keys in uppercase

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568494/keyup-event-always-return-uppercase-letter

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have a mistake in your code.

> replace `onkeyup` with just `keyup`

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("keyup", logKey)

function logKey(e) {
   log.textContent += e.code;
}
```

```css
#d {
  width:50%;
  color:red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="d"> </div>

<p id="log"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `onkeyup` to`keyup`

```js
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("keyup", logKey)

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="d"> </div>

<p id="log"></p>
```

You can also use `e.key` instead of `code`

```js
const log = document.getElementById('log');

document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("keyup", logKey)

function logKey(e) {
  log.textContent += ` ${e.key}`;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="d"> </div>

<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: How to just get the key pressed? For example `e.code` always gives the typed character in uppercase

Comment: You want in lower case? What is the expected result?

Comment: I want to get the key pressed. If I press `s` then I expect `s`. If I press `S` , I expect `S`